# How to access Cassandra Database from Delphi?

Tags: delphi, cassandra, database, nosql

DataStax academy is not providing drivers for Delphi. How to access Cassandra Database from Delphi?

Comment: There is a C++ client library, this could be a starting point for a Delphi integration. See http://www.planetcassandra.org/client-drivers-tools/

Comment: A while a go I made tiny Delphi connectors to MongoDB, SQLite, Redis, CouchDB just to get to know these better. I'll add Cassandra to the list, and might have a try some day soon. (Keep an eye out [here](https://github.com/stijnsanders?tab=repositories))

Comment: (also, [seen this?](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/15/09/22/2145258/cassandra-rewritten-in-c-ten-times-faster))

Comment: According to my Understanding, ScyllaDB is not supported for Windows platform. And there is no chance for altering a Table or Keyspace. So, I think I cannot use ScyllaDB for my Delphi application. @Stijn Sanders

Comment: @mjn how to integrate c++ client library in Delphi? can we do that?